# Vue 3: how to pass $store and $i18n to createVNode()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, internationalization, vuex

I need to create a dynamic component in a `Vue 3` app. Here is the code that I've got:

```
let el = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
let vNode = createVNode(DeviceSettings, { device: this.device });

render(vNode, el);
```

However, when I try to run this component I get errors about `$store` and `$i18n`. So, how do I pass the `vuex` and `i18n` instances to the new component?

I tried:

```
createVNode({DeviceSettings, store, i18n}, { device: this.device });
```

and other variations of this but it did not work.

I looked [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/060c5f1d0ae999cd8c8fb965e8526ffab17ac2d1/packages/runtime-core/src/vnode.ts#L326) for the definition of the `createVNode` function but it seems there is no way to pass that kind of stuff to it.

I googled various things and came empty-handed.

Any ideas?

Comment: " I get errors about $store and $i18n" - which errors? This is potentially XY problem. You create a new sub-app, not just dynamic component. Even if you pass store and i18n, you will have reactivity problems because these are different apps. Use standard ways to create dynamic comp, i.e. <component> or <teleport> depending on your case